# Feedback on my Translation of Yeats into Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, poetry

I'm looking for feedback on my rendition of W.B. Yeats' poem *Who Goes with Fergus?* (1893).  Comments, corrections, emendations and suggestions are all welcome.

Here's the original poem:

> Who will go drive with Fergus now,
> And pierce the deep wood's woven shade,
> And dance upon the level shore?
> Young man, lift up your russet brow,
> And lift your tender eyelids, maid,
> And brood on hopes and fear no more.
>
> And no more turn aside and brood
> Upon love's bitter mystery;
> For Fergus rules the brazen cars,
> And rules the shadows of the wood,
> And the white breast of the dim sea
> And all dishevelled wandering stars.

And here's my translation:

> Quisnam ibit, et cum Fergo impellet biiugos,
> ut figat textam profundi nemoris umbram,
> et plana per litora indulgeat choreis?
> Ad lucem, o iuvenis, frontem fulvedine tinctam
> attolle; tu quoque, virgo, tenues attolle palpebras:
> nec amplius spebus metibusque incubetis.
>
> Nec aversis vultibus amplius incubetis
> amorum arcanis, occultis et amaris,
> nam Fergus imperat curribus aeneis:
> et imperat umbris nemoribus inclusis,
> et pectoribus obscuri aequoris perlucidis,
> et cunctis errantibus sine ordine astris.

My translation is in no proper meter, but I tried to maintain some rough rhythm in every line, which may explain some of the liberties I took with the original.  You might know this poem from James Joyce’s *Ulysses;* it comes up a few times towards the beginning of the book.